# В vscode на маке не закрываются кавычки автоматически

Tags: visual-studio-code, кавычки

В vscode на маке не закрываются кавычки автоматически, а скобки закрываются. В настройках стоит авто (см. скрин). Расширения поудалял лишние.
[image: скриншот vscode]

Comment: А причем тут настройка с "auto"? Это сюда никак не относится.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено здесь, если у кого-то такая же проблема будет. Нужно изменить в раскладке клавиатуры с US Internationall на US - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45808557/autoclose-single-and-double-quotes-vscode